# asp.net reading code behind file variables

Tags: asp.net

I have a web form having a grid bonded to SQL data source. But the select command of the SQL data source is dynamically accepted and stored in a static class which resides in app_code file of my project. How do I set the select command of the SQL data source to this query in the app_code class?

I did something like this :

```
<script type="text/C#" runat="server" language="c#" src="ReportGenerationGrid.aspx.cs">
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = ParametersRetainer.Query;
</script>
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = ParametersRetainer.Query;
}
```

or if you don't use a code behind file then you could do it inline:

```
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = ParametersRetainer.Query;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov i tried both the approaches but its not working.If I hard code the command it works,but doesn't work like this.